# Google Maps, Java Script, add 2nd adress on the map

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I got the code where I can put address instead of latitude and it displays on the map, that part works fine, I added second *var addresss* but this is as far i can go with my knowlodge for coding, please help

```
    <html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Geocoding Simple</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var geocoder;
  var map;
  var address ="UNIT 1A LOWER TINAHISK  SOUTH QUAY  ARKLOW  co.wicklow";
  var addresss ="UNIT 4 INDUSTRIAL ESTATE   DONORE ROAD DROGHEDA    CO LOUTH";
  function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 9,
      center: latlng,
     mapTypeControl: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
    navigationControl: true,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    if (geocoder) {
      geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
          if (status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {
          map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
                { content: '<b>'+address+'</b>',
              size: new google.maps.Size(150,50)
                });

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: results[0].geometry.location,
                map: map, 
                title:address
            }); 
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                infowindow.open(map,marker);
            });

          } else {
            alert("No results found");
          }
        } else {
          alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
      });
    }
  }
</script>
</head>
<body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;" onload="initialize()">
 <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%">
    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Java.  It is as similar to Javascript as Car is to Carpet.

Comment: @JoeC sorry, u right

Comment: at the moment you are only geocoding `address` you need to call a function to geocode each address you want to geocode.

Comment: @PaulThomasGC how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the addresses in an array and run the geocode on each item.

[Working example here](https://jsfiddle.net/v4csufaz/)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var geocoder;
  var map;

  var addresses = [
   "UNIT 1A LOWER TINAHISK  SOUTH QUAY  ARKLOW  co.wicklow",
   "UNIT 4 INDUSTRIAL ESTATE   DONORE ROAD DROGHEDA    CO LOUTH"
  ]

function initialize() {

geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);

var myOptions = {
  zoom: 9,
  center: latlng,
  mapTypeControl: true,
  mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
  navigationControl: true,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

// Geocode each address
addresses.forEach( function(address) {
    geocode(address)
});
}

// Function to geocode addresses
function geocode(address) {
if (geocoder) {
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      if (status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {

        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
          { content: '<b>'+address+'</b>',
           size: new google.maps.Size(150,50)
          }
        );

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: results[0].geometry.location,
          map: map, 
          title:address
        }); 

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
          infowindow.open(map,marker);
        });

      } else {
        alert("No results found");
      }

    } else {

      alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
    }
  });
}
}
</script>
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:750px; height:750px">
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initialize"></script>
```